# TypeError : strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

Tags: python, datetime, python-unittest

I'm new in Python. I have a `util.py` file to check the value of datetime. I writed a test case for it with value is None. But I got error `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None`. Would someone please tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

My `util.py` :

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import traceback
import time
from analyzer.analyzerlogging import setup_stopwatch, setup_logger


def validate_date(logger, val, parameter_name, date_format, date_format_info):
    """ Check if val is the date with correct format, then return the date
    """
    _val = None
    try:
        _val = datetime.strptime(val, date_format)
    except ValueError:
        msg = f"Invalid value {val} of parameter {parameter_name}. {parameter_name.capitalize()} should be at format '{date_format_info}'"
        logger.error(msg)
        raise Exception(msg)
    return _val
```

My test case :

```
import unittest
from analyzer.util import validate_date
from datetime import date
import datetime
from analyzer.analyzerlogging import setup_logger


class TestUtilValidateDate(unittest.TestCase):

#val is None and date_format_info is YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss
    def test_UT_UTIL_VALIDATE_DATE_005(self):
        try:
            validate_date(self.logger, None, 'param_name', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
        except Exception as e:
            result = "Invalid value None of parameter param_name. Param_name should be at format 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'"
            self.assertEqual(str(e),result)
```

Error :

```
test_UT_UTIL_VALIDATE_DATE_005 (test_util_validate_date.TestUtilValidateDate) ... FAIL
NoneType: None

======================================================================
FAIL: test_UT_UTIL_VALIDATE_DATE_005 (test_util_validate_date.TestUtilValidateDate)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\duongnb\Documents\SVN\trunk\src\Analyzer\toshiba\yieldnews\ut\test_util_validate_date.py", line 44, in test_UT_UTIL_VALIDATE_DATE_005
    validate_date(self.logger, None, 'param_name', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\duongnb\Documents\SVN\trunk\src\Analyzer\toshiba\yieldnews\ut\test_util_validate_date.py", line 47, in test_UT_UTIL_VALIDATE_DATE_005
    self.assertEqual(str(e),result)
AssertionError: 'strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None' != "Invalid value None of parameter param_na[52 chars]:ss'"
- strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None
+ Invalid value None of parameter param_name. Param_name should be at format 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: try replacing the ValueError in to TypeError or add another exception TypeError in util.py

Comment: Also, use `with self.assertRaises(TypeError, msg='...'):` instead of adding your own exception handler in the test. And always check for specific exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unittest has worked correctly in your code - it indicates your try/except is not capturing the correct exception. Change your exception to `TypeError` and it will be caught and the message returned.

You should use `self.assertRaisesMesssage` if your aim is to check the expected error and error message that passing in `None` as arg1 produces.

```
mock_val = None
parameter_name = 'Foo'
date_format_info = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
expected_msg = f"Invalid value {mock_val} of parameter {parameter_name}. {parameter_name.capitalize()} should be at format '{date_format_info}'"

with self.assertRaisesMessage(TypeError, expected_msg):
    validate_date(self.logger, mock_val, parameter_name, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', date_format_info)
```